# Trying to get code to pass and keep statistics without using global variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

new to coding and trying a simple rock, paper, scissors game. need to display statistics when the user exits, without using global variances. Currently it just prints win=0,loss=0,tie=0 no matter how many times the loop has been run. Looking for a way to pass the wins, losses, and ties as parameters and have them save until the user exits the loop.

---

```
def the_game(computer_play,user_play): 
    win=0
    loss=0
    tie=0

    print('You chose',user_play,',computer chose',computer_play)
    if user_play=='Rock':
        if computer_play=='Rock':
            print("I'ts a tie!")
            tie+=1
            return tie
        elif computer_play=='Paper':
            print('Paper covers Rock.\ncomputer wins!')
            loss+=1
            return loss
        elif computer_play=='Scissors':
            print('Rock smashes Scissors.\nplayer wins!')
            win+=1
            return win
    
    elif user_play=='Paper':
        if computer_play=='Rock':
            print("Paper covers Rock.\nplayer wins!")
            win+=1
            return win
    
        elif computer_play=='Paper':
            print("I'ts a tie!")
            tie+=1
            return tie
        elif computer_play=='Scissors':
            print('Scissors cut Paper.\ncomputer wins!')
            loss+=1
            return loss
    else:
        if computer_play=='Rock':
            print('Rock smashes Scissors.\ncomputer wins!')
            loss+=1
            return loss
        elif computer_play=='Paper':
            print('Scissors cut paper.\nplayer wins')
            win+=1
            return win
    
        elif computer_play=='Scissors':
            print("It's a tie!")
            tie+=1
            return tie

    
def display_stats(num1,num2,num3):
    print('Wins: ',num1,'\nLosses: ',num2,'\nTies: ',num3)
    
    
def play_again():
    again=input('Want to play again? (y/n): ')
    if again=='y':
        return True
    else:
        return False
                                
def main():
    win=0
    loss=0
    tie=0
    again=True
    displayintro()
   
    while again:
        user=get_user_play()
        computer=get_computer_play()
        the_game(computer,user)
        again=play_again()
    else:
        display_stats(win,loss,tie)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to separate your code into functions *based on what they do!* *Don't* include the code to track statistics *inside* the function that handles the actual game. Instead, have the game return the result and increment the correct counter *outside* the game function. For example,

```
def the_game(computer, user):
    if <tie condition>:
        return 0
    elif <win condition>:
        return 1
    else: # loss
        return -1
```

Then, in your `main()` function,

```
def main():
    win=0
    loss=0
    tie=0
    again=True
    displayintro()
   
    while again:
        user=get_user_play()
        computer=get_computer_play()
        result = the_game(computer,user)
        if result == 1: win += 1
        elif result == 0: tie += 1
        else: loss += 1
        again=play_again()
    else:
        display_stats(win,loss,tie)
```

Other slight improvements:

Instead of writing all those nested `if-elif-else`, you can simply create a dictionary defining which moves are beaten by each move.

```
winning_moves = { "R": "S", # rock beats scissor
                  "S": "P", # scissor beats paper
                  "P": "R"  # paper beats rock
                }
```

Then, you have two conditions to check:

```
def the_game(computer, user):
    if computer == user: 
        return 0 # this is a tie
    elif winning_moves[user] == computer:
        return 1 # User's move beats computer's move
    else:
        return -1
```

To include your words ("rock smashes scissors", etc.), you could also add that into your dictionary:

```
winning_moves = { "R": ("S", "smashes"), # rock smashesscissor
                  "S": ("P", "cut"), # scissor cuts paper
                  "P": ("R", "covers")  # paper covers rock
                }
```

```
def the_game(computer, user):
    if computer == user:
        print("It's a tie!") 
        return 0 # this is a tie
    elif winning_moves[user][0] == computer:
        verb = winning_moves[user][1]
        message = f"{user} {verb} {computer}.\nYou win!"
        print(message)
        return 1 # User's move beats computer's move
    else:
        verb = winning_moves[computer][1]
        message = f"{computer} {verb} {user}.\nComputer wins!"
        print(message)
        return -1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try not to separate your code into functions because it causes problems like this -  functions are only useful if you need to reuse the code inside them. I'd also recommend changing the `else` statement in `play_again()` to an elif statement :)